# Можно ли однопоточный node.js Angular проект собирать на нескольких ядрах процессора?

Tags: node.js, angular, cluster

Можно ли однопоточный node.js Angular проект собирать на нескольких ядрах процессора что б увеличить скорость сборки?

Comment: можно использовать esbuild https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/blob/master/docs/architecture.md#design-principles

Comment: А вы уверены, что стоит этим заниматься? Насколько часто требуется собирать приложение, сколько оно занимает. В чем причина? Если речь идет о CI процессах где-нибудь в докер-образе, то чаще смотрят на распараллеливание тестов, а также кэшируют node_modules, чтобы не качать их каждый раз. Конкретно ваша проблема не совсем ясна.

Comment: @"Sergey Glazirin" ну на данный момент проект пересобирается не очень быстро даже учитывая что у меня проц Apple m1Max- но так как изначально в проекте много лишнего и переписать с нуля не представляется возможным а так же подчистить все не так то легко и оптимизировать весь код- вот я и ищу варианты- как мне ускорить сборку проекта в дев версии